# Can ESP32 be the one who starts bluetooth connection to Android device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I have a M5StickC device, that is basically a battery operated ESP32.

**What I want to achieve:** I want the M5StickC device to wirelessly cause an Android device do something when a button is pressed on the M5StickC. The M5StickC should only wake up when button is pressed, do the thing and then sleep and wake up again when button is pressed again.

**What I have tried**: I have found example codes on the internet and was able to make a 2-way BT serial connection, but the problem is that *the Android device is the one that starts the connection*. Also I would have to keep the devices connected all the time to receive button presses. As the M5StickC device is battery operated, it needs to conserve power and can not be on 24/7. Also it does not look like a good idea to constantly try to connect to the M5Stick device from Android (by polling) and asking whether the button was pressed, as that will probably drain the phone battery.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction how to achieve this? I am experienced in software development, so I can figure things out. I am just lost right now.

(I don't care if it's Bluetooth Classic or BLE.)

Comment: Both devices are battery powered so both devices want to shut down their respective radios. Once disconnected, the receiver has to rescan/listen to get the state of the sender (BLE Advertisement). If you want long life battery you may have to change to dedicated hardware (or get a bigger battery). I was thinking of the TI Sensor Tag and found [this discussion](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/issues/1305) but regardless Android has Doze mode which will shutdown any listening activity by Android (again battery life).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let Android be the central and use connectGatt with the autoConnect parameter set to true. That will result in a low duty cycle initiate attempt as well as automatic re-connect attempts that won't drain the battery.